# Rotating a matrix in a non standard 2d plane

Tags: matrix, rotation, geometry, 2d

I have some problems figuring out how to rotate a matrix in a 2d plane since my coordinate system is not a standard mathematical one, my plane has an inverted y-axis, meaning higher y value is lower on the screen. I also want to rotate the matrix clockwise instead of the standard anticlockwise.

So if I try to illustrate how I want it to work:

O = origin
X = points to rotate

Then 0 degrees looks like this:

```
XXX
 O
```

I want 90 degrees to look like this:

```
  X
 OX
  X
```

180 degrees should look like this:

```
 O
XXX
```

270 degrees should look like this:

```
X
XO
X
```

Any ideas on how to calculate the new x and y for a point after rotating in this plane?

Comment: You do not show your code but my bet is that you implemented X=aX+bY, Y=a'X+b'Y, which is wrong: the X in the second assignment is the rotated X, whereas it should be the original one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clockwise rather than anti-clockwise just means flipping the sign on the angle.

To get the full result, we just transform into 'standard coords', do the rotation, and transform back:

The coordinate transform and its inverse is:

```
(x') = ( 1  0 ) (x)
(y')   ( 0 -1 ) (y)
```

A rotation anti-clockwise is:

```
(x') = (  cos(angle) -sin(angle) ) (x)
(y')   (  sin(angle)  cos(angle) ) (y)
```

So a rotation clockwise is:

```
(x') = (  cos(angle)  sin(angle) ) (x)
(y')   ( -sin(angle)  cos(angle) ) (y)
```

Altogether this gives:

```
(x') = ( 1  0 )(  cos(angle)  sin(angle) ) ( 1  0 )(x)
(y')   ( 0 -1 )( -sin(angle)  cos(angle) ) ( 0 -1 )(y)
```

Multiply the matrices to get:

```
(x') = (  cos(angle)  sin(angle) ) (x)
(y')   ( -sin(angle)  cos(angle) ) (y)
```

Now, as you may by now have realized, this is actually the same matrix as rotating 'standard coords' in the anti-clockwise direction.

Or in code:

```
// Angle in radians
double x2 =  cos(angle) * x1 - sin(angle) * y1;
double y2 =  sin(angle) * x1 + cos(angle) * y1;
```

For example, if angle is 180 degrees, `cos(angle)` is `-1`, and `sin` is `0`, giving:

```
double x2 =  -x1;
double y2 =  -y1;
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the code and I get the right effect for 0 and 90 degrees. But at 180 degrees my points (-1,0) (0,0) (1,0) turns into (1,1) (0,0) (-1,-1) (should be (1,0) (0,0) (-1,0)) and at 270 degrees they turn into (-1,0) (0,0) (1,0) (should be (0,1) (0,0) (0,-1))

Comment: See edit for 180 degrees example - where's the problem?